# Webscaping table data with drop down menu help in either Pandas, Beautiful Soup or Selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I am trying to scrape data from this website:

https://www.shanghairanking.com/rankings/grsssd/2021

Initially pandas gets me out the gates and I can scrape the table but I am struggling with the drop down menus. I want to select the options next to the total score box which are PUB, CIT, etc. When I inspect the element it looks like maybe Javascript and the usual methods of interating over these options don't work. I have tried Beutifalsoup and most recently Selenium to select the drop downs by hand. This works for the default table data
'''

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/martinbell/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.shanghairanking.com/rankings/grsssd/2021')
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='CIT']").click()
```

'''
Doesn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would not work as you first have to click the dropdown open and then traverse through the options in the dropdown. Here is the refactored code.

Note that I have used `time.sleep` for instant purposes but for a robust code and good practice, use explicit wait such as `WebdriverWait`

```
driver.get('https://www.shanghairanking.com/rankings/grsssd/2021')
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@class='inputWrapper'])[3]").click()
#The below commented code loops through all the dropdown options and performs actions.
# opt_ele = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//*[@class='rank-select'])[2]//*[@class='options']//li")
# for ele in opt_ele:
#     print(ele.text)
#     ele.click()
#     print('perform your actions here')
#     driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@class='inputWrapper'])[3]").click()

# If you do not want to loop through but just want to select only CIT, here is the line:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@class='rank-select'])[2]//*[@class='options']//li[text()='CIT']").click()
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks that worked for me. I forgot to ask - is there an easy way to deal with pagination as well. I will have a go using the example you have above.

Comment: @Martin Please accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: @Martin you may use this //li[@title='Next Page'] to keep clicking on next page. Before that, you have to check if the element is clickable or not. It would be clickable until all the pages are done, and it gets disabled when it reaches the last page, and when it becomes non-clickable you may exit/break the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I still can get the exact code for this to work as I am new to Selenium. The  //li[@title='Next Page'] doesn't get me anywhere and I have been trying to get the correct Xcode. Any help appreciated. Thanks Martin

Comment: next_page = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content-box"]')
next_page = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[@class=' ant-pagination-next']")
next_page = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "[@class='ant-pagination-item-link']")

Comment: The code above just produces lists. :-(